# How to get value of one column into another column based on matching array indexes

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to match arrays by taking an index of 1st array and looping through the 2nd to match string(for example emails), and then use the range of the 2nd array to getvalue of one column to another. I managed to store the data I want into the arrays and match them, however I'm still not able to setvalues from one column to the next based on index range. Here is what I've tried so far, keep in mind I am new to Google Scripts and coding so I'm pretty sure my problems are simple.

````
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  // gets current active sheet
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // stores values in dedicated arrays 
  var emailAdd1 = activeSheet.getRange("B2:B260").getValues();
  var emailAdd2 = activeSheet.getRange("C2:C260").getValues(); 
  //counter variables 

    var checker=0;
  var num=0;
 

// =cycles through arrays & compares indexes  
    while (checker > emailAdd2.length) {
        if (emailAdd1.indexOf(checker)==emailAdd2.indexOf(num)){
            //store column data corresponding to 2nd array range
            var idNum = activeSheet.getRange(checker,1).getValue();
            //set data into other column
              activeSheet.getRange(num,4).setValue(idNum);
              //reset num to start cycle through 2nd array
          num=0;
          checker++;
        }
        
        else { 
        //increment to check next index of 2nd array
        num++;
        }

    }```


[Diagram of Concepts][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXy6w.png
Here is a visual incase I didn't explain myself properly
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, here's the process you want to achieve:

1. Each emails on column B will scan all rows of Column C to check for any matching emails
2. If there is, copy & put the ID from Column A to Column D on the row of the matched email on Column C

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTION:**

I've created a **sample sheet** below with sample data (based on the sample image you've attached):

[image]

**SCRIPT**

```
function scanEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var email1 = ss.getRange("A2:B"+ss.getDataRange().getLastRow()).getValues(); //Gets the ID and the Old email data (it contains ID & OLD EMAIL or email1[0][1] on every index)
  
  for(var x=2; x <= ss.getDataRange().getLastRow(); x++ ){ //Loop through the Column C to view all of its values
      email1.forEach(res => { //Perform a ForEach loop to loop through the "email1" array 
        if(res[1] == ss.getRange(x,3).getValue()){ //Check if res[1] or the "OLD EMAIL" index matches the for loop Column C row (x) value
          Logger.log("Found a match for "+res[1]+"\n============COLUMN C============\nCell C"+x+"\nValue: \""+ ss.getRange(x,3).getValue()+"\"\n================================"); //Log result for review
          ss.getRange(x,4).setValue(res[0]); //Sets the OLD email ID into the row of the matched email on Column C
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Here's the execution log result for you to review:

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain how the inside of the for loop works?

Comment: Sure. Firstly, I have put all of the OLD EMAILS and their IDs ("A2:B") into an array variable "email1" (it contains ID & OLD EMAIL or email1[0][1] on every index). Then, I've performed a For Loop on Column C. Inside the for loop, I have performed a For Each loop to check if each array index in email1[1]  (or OLD EMAIL) matches the first loop (x) value on Column C and then if there's a match, add the email1[0] (or ID)  on column D based on the Column C row number (x).